# The text on my button wont change

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

First time using asp/web forms I thought the following code would change my web forms button. but when I run the 'site' and click the button it just seems to refresh the page but not change the text of the button.  I dragged the button from the tool box as normal.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Text = "result";           
}
```

Is there something else I need to do when using web forms?

UPDATE UI SOURCE CODE

```
  <p>
                ASP.NET555 Web Forms lets you build dynamic websites using a familiar drag-and-drop, event-driven model.
            A design surface and hundreds of controls and components let you rapidly build sophisticated, powerful UI-driven sites with data access.
                <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
                </asp:Table>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" Width="244px" />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="555"></asp:Label>
                555test</p>
```

The button appears to point correctly to the Button1_Click event.

Comment: Did you bound event on page in aspx page? OnClick = "Button1_Click" and put a break point, see if it even hits

Comment: please add the client side page to the example

Comment: Are you setting `Button1.Text` elsewhere?

Comment: Did you debug the solution? How about setting the break point in `Button1_Click` event handler and checking it is called?

Comment: yes it does not seem to hit the code at all.

Comment: This code does work. Have you tried restarting Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

one reason may be Event may not created for the button
u can check it by remove the event handler add it ones more this may solve your issue with button event

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" />
```

Check on-click event is correct on your UI Elements

The case of copying method also will get effect
else

if you added  `CausesValidation = "True"` attribute of button This is also a one reason event may not fire

update ur UI code of the button

Comment: I have added the UI source